# Setting Up Rails to Receive HTTP POST Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, post, request

Is setting up Rails to receive a HTTP POST request that sends information encoded in JSON form as easy as adding the following code to the sessions_controller?  Or are there other steps involved?

```
def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params["email"], params["password"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    render:json => "{\"r\": \"t\"}" + req
else
    render :json => "{\"r\": \"f\"}"
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be that easy, though you will need to add a route to your `routes.rb` file as well specifying POST as the HTTP verb and pointing it to `sessions#create`.  You also might want to use [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) just to validate what parameters are required and which you'll accept.  As a heads up, I'm not entirely sure what `"{\"r\": \"t\"}" + req` is supposed to represent.  It looks like `req` would be undefined in this case, but perhaps you're just omitting some code.  Lastly, `render :json => ...` is sort of the old way of including a hash.  I believe as of Ruby 2 the standard is something more like `render json: ...`.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Do you recommend taking out "{\"r\": \"t\"}"+req" or just taking out the  "+ req" or replacing it with something else?

Comment: I'm just not sure what that represents ... Perhaps you could elaborate on what you're trying to return to whoever is calling your method.